# Laravel8: Class not found despite defining it in the models

Tags: php, laravel

I used the model "clients.php" but when I load in the ClientsController

`$clients= Client::all()->sortby('name');`

> I get the: Class "App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Client" not found

What would be the solution? I knew that if I create a "clients" model, then it should load as "client" in my function

Comment: The file needs to be `Client.php` not `clients.php`

Comment: You must check if you have imported Clinet Model in your ClientController. If not imported then add `use App\Models\Client;` at top of your ClientController.

Answer (score 5):

You should use full namespace, for example (if Client model is stored inside Models directory):

```
$clients = \App\Models\Client::all()->sortby('name');
```

or you can add `use App\Models\Client;` at the beginning of the file after the namespace declaration and then just use

```
$clients = Client::all()->sortby('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the Client model. If you use **Laravel 8** then :

```php
use App\Models\Client;

$clients = Client::all()->sortby('name');
```

#### OR

If you use **Laravel 7** or below then:

```php
use App\Client;

$clients = Client::all()->sortby('name');
```

Comment: Correct solution, only, the namespace is not different for the Laravel version, but depends on where the file is located (I personally use a Models folder in Laravel 7 too)

Comment: @GertB. You are right. But by default this would the correct pathes.

Answer (score 0):

you can do .
use your client controller

```
use App\Models\Client;
```

then

```
$clients= Client::all()->sortBy('name');
```

**OR**

call direct model in your controller.

```
$clients = \App\Models\Client::all()->sortBy('name');
```